# How To Include Token With Mac .App

Tags: macos, token

I've got a text token I'd like to include with an App I'm serving from a web server. What I'd hoped to do was include it in the file name, but every attempt I've made to do that has failed. What's the best way to convey user specific data with a downloaded App?

Comment: What do you mean by "text token"? What do you mean by include it in the filename? What is the user-specific data? Question is not clear.

Comment: It's a guid that relates to a user session. Once the user downloads the file, I'd like it to be aware of what session it came from.